# How to Scrape Product with category from Magento based site

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export

I need to copy around 19000 product from site 123inkjet.com.
But I have some issue , I can extract category easily.
Only issue in product , I used online extractor tools like 
http://webscraper.io/ , But issue is magento architecture.
I need a solution for scraping data from magento site and easily import in magento based site.

Is any extension is coming for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the terms and conditions of the website you want to scrape:

   For 123inkjet.com: http://www.123inkjets.com/terms

   > ### 15. Prohibited Uses
   >
   > 123inkjets imposes certain restrictions on Your use of the Website and
   >   the Services. You represent and warrant that You will not, without
   >   limitation: (a) violate or attempt to violate any security features of
   >   the Website or Services; **(b) copy or otherwise duplicate, directly or
   >   indirectly, any portion of the Website, including without limitation,
   >   all product listings, prices or descriptions, designs, information,
   >   photographs, images, drawings, videos, music, text, typefaces,
   >   graphics, code, and other files, and the selection, arrangement and
   >   organization thereof (collectively, "123inkjets Content");** (c) use any
   >   software that enables copying or duplication of the 123inkjets Content
   >   for later off-line viewing; (d) distribute, display, modify, transmit,
   >   resell, reuse, or repost the 123inkjets in any electronic form,
   >   including any online service, the Internet or any other
   >   telecommunications medium which now exists or shall exist in the
   >   future, for any purpose, without the prior written permission of
   >   123inkjets; (e) provide false, misleading or inaccurate information to
   >   123inkjets; (f) impersonate, or otherwise misrepresent affiliation,
   >   connection or association with, any person or entity; (g) harvest or
   >   otherwise collect information about 123inkjets users, including email
   >   addresses and phone numbers; (h) use or attempt to use any engine,
   >   software, tool, agent, or other device or mechanism (including without
   >   limitation browsers, spiders, robots, avatars, or intelligent agents)
   >   to harvest or otherwise collect information from the Website for any
   >   use, including without limitation use on third-party websites; (i)
   >   access content or data not intended for You, or log onto a server or
   >   account that You are not authorized to access; (j) attempt to probe,
   >   scan, or test the vulnerability of the Services, the Website, or any
   >   associated system or network, or breach security or authentication
   >   measures without proper authorization; (k) interfere or attempt to
   >   interfere with the use of the Website or Services by any other user,
   >   host or network, including, without limitation by means of submitting
   >   a virus, overloading, "flooding," "spamming," "mail bombing," or
   >   "crashing"; (l) use the Website or Services to send unsolicited
   >   e-mail, including without limitation, email promotions or
   >   advertisements for products or services; (m) forge any TCP/IP packet
   >   header or any part of the header information in any e-mail or in any
   >   uploading or posting to, or transmission, display, performance or
   >   distribution by means of, the Website or Services; or (n) attempt to
   >   modify, reverse-engineer, decompile, disassemble or otherwise reduce
   >   or attempt to reduce to a human-perceivable form any of the source
   >   code used in providing the Website or Services. **Any violation of this
   >   section may subject You to civil and/or criminal liability.**

   (highlight added)
2. Now you have to ask for permissions to use content from their site, you can as well ask them for an XML or CSV product feed that you can import.